# Unable to log into Local Server -gds_db InterBase Developer Edition

Tags: authentication, server, local, interbase

Unable to log into Local Server -gds_db after download of Interbase Developer Edition. Getting "Error logging into the requested server" Connection rejected by remote interface' .Using un/pw of SYSDBA masterkey.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more detail?

- Is this the only InterBase instance installed on your machine? You don't have any prior older InterBase version, or Firebird on the system, right?
- Did you register it with the Developer Edition, and start the InterBase Server using the IBMgr tool from the InterBase install? I am assuming you are using Windows, and not Linux.
- Are you seeing this error in IBConsole GUI? Or, are you seeing errors when connecting from the command line tool, isql.exe (isql on Linux)?
- From command line, do the following to test...
  <interbase_path>/bin/isql.exe -user sysdba -password masterkey C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\InterBase\gds_db\examples\database\employee.gdb

Are you able to connect with above?

Also, provide the contents of C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\InterBase\gds_db\interbase.log; it might have some clues if the server did not start properly.